# Cite and create bibliography in texstudio with IEEE Transaction template (Windows, Mendeley)

Tags: texstudio, templates, ieeetran, windows, mendeley

After I reviewed similar StackExchange questions, I've decided to ask;

I want to write an article using [the IEEE transaction LaTeX template](https://template-selector.ieee.org/secure/templateSelector/downloadTemplate?publicationTypeId=1&titleId=37&articleId=3&fileId=295). I use Mendeley as a reference manager and TeXstudio as editor. My OS is Windows.
First, I've created my bib files from Mendeley/Options/BibTeX by selecting *Create one BibTeX file per group* "in the same folder" as my tex file. You will see the original bib file names in the code below, but I did not know whether the problem originated there, so I tried to do it with two simple names such as bib1 and bib2.
I cite references in-text using the `\cite` command. For example, `\cite{Tan2019}, \cite{Valente2019}`. For the bibliography section, my code is,

```
\begin{thebibliography}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{Journals & Proceedings-Autonomous Driving,Journals & Proceedings-Visual Odometry}
\end{thebibliography}
```

As mentioned, I tried `\bibliography{bib1, bib2}`.
So I am getting the following error message: `Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item. \begin{thebibliography}{}`

I couldn't see the proper in-text citation and a bibliography. How can I do that correctly? Or do you advise any method to write an IEEE article in Texstudio with Mendeley on Windows?

Comment: `\bibliography{mybibfile}` *replaces* the `thebibliography` environment, drop `\begin{thebibliography}` and `\end{thebibliography}`.  You will then need to [run `bibtex`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/63875/106162) as well as `(pdf)latex` and it should just work with a correctly formed bib file.

Comment: Thanks, this solved my problem. I don't understand why IEEE doesn't update those issues in templates.
 What do you mean by "run BibTeX, then LaTeX" ? There are similar advice on Internet: 
$ latex myarticle
$ bibtex myarticle
$ latex myarticle
$ latex myarticle 
I work with Windows. I don't  understand  "running BibTeX."

Comment: Fully manual compilation requires running a separate executable `bibtex` as well as `latex`, some editors will do this for you. If your bibliography is appearing correctly after using just `\bibliography{mybibfile}` then you probably don't need to worry about it right now, if that changes or you're generally interested have a read of the linked question "[Question mark or bold citation key instead of citation number](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/106162)".